# java text tools

Tags: java, text

I need to deal with text mostly txt format. I usually use java and read or write the txt file,and get or deal with the text. I find it's not work efficiently 。
   I need to find another tools to find deal with text efficiently. Any suggestion?
   Thanks in advance.

More infomation:
   I have a file crontab.conf and its contents like this:

```
# every 30 mins
[0 0,30 * * * *]
cmd_applog
cmd_coreparam


#every 4h
[0 1 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * *]
cmd_vgstatus
cmd_diskcheck

# every 5 secs
[0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * *]
process_number
```

crontab.conf's content like this. Now, I have a command name like 'ls_info' and this command which execute every 5 secs. In that case, first, I'll look up crontab.conf and find whether its contains a command whose name is 'ls_info', if yes, I add this command like this:

```
 # every 5 secs
 [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * *]
 ls_info
```

add a new command to the file is simple, but update this file is not an easy thing for me. suppose we already have a command named 'cmd_vgstatus' in crontab.conf, now I firstly find this command exist and then according to this command's frequency(we suppose 5 secs),
I find 'cmd_vgstatus' will be execute every 4h originally, so in this case I need to do a lot.

```
1.how can I check command's frequency by a number, such as 5 sec.
```

And I need to match 5 with [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * *].
   what's more, the frequency may be 5 sec or maybe 10 min ,its dynamic.

```
2.now I matched frequency successfully.
```

I need to delete command name from it's original frequency and add it to the new frequency. How can I marked the line number?

Comment: What's not working efficiently?

Comment: Efficiently in terms of programmer productivity or runtime performance?  If your problem is the former then try a scripting language like Perl, Ruby, or Python.  If it's the latter then Java is a fine choice; perhaps there is some algorithmic complexity problem.

Comment: @Korhan & maerics, I update my question, could you please give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Perl is great for dealing with text files.
If you want better answers, you need to be a bit more specific in your question.

Comment: thanks slipset, I update my question. Could you please give me some advice?